# Neo4J / Cypher: How to filter for the path with the latest date in the relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I an new to querying with Cypher.

```
(p:Person)-[e:Evaluated {rating:3, characteristic: "quality of kitchen", date: 14-09-2009})->(h:House {adress: xyz})
```

Every house has multiple characteristics.
Every house is rated multiple times (on different dates).

What I want to achieve is to match path (p)-[e]-(h), but I want to filter for only the paths with the most recent evaluation date.

This path is the starting point for further analysis.

This filter should probably work with WITH or WHERE function, but after a lot of struggling with the query I try my luck here :)

Comment: Take a look at https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/limiting-match-results-per-row/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For simplicity, I will assume that you will first change the `date` property to be easily ordered (e.g., you use a [date](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/date/#functions-date-calendar) value,  or you use the format '2009-09-14').*

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get the single latest result:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[e:Evaluated {rating:3, characteristic: "quality of kitchen"}]->(h:House {address: '123 Main St'})
RETURN p, e, h
ORDER BY e.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```